# SharePoint 2013 Image Rendition Quality

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there any way to set the quality of the image rendition feature? 
By default it creates images with a low setting that produces a lot of compression artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by image rendition quality. If you mean compression quality I cannot help, but you can change the resolution using the SharePoint Design Manager.

> 1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure has,
>      at minimum, Design permissions to the top-level site of the site
>      collection.
> 2. In a browser, go to the top-level site of the publishing
>      site collection.
> 3. Choose the Settings icon. On the Site Settings
>      page, in the Look and Feel section, choose Image Renditions.
> 4. On the Image Renditions page,
>      choose Add new item.
> 5. On the New Image Rendition page, in the Name
>      box, enter a name for the rendition. For example, enter
>      Thumbnail_Small.
> 6. In the Width and Height text boxes, enter the width
>      and height, in pixels, of the rendition, and then choose Save.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj720398(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj720398%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

EDIT:

I've done some research and it seems that there is no way to change the image encoding quality!
Take a look at this MSDN thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/da7ff7ca-0064-4ada-a6a5-d007b3714233/encoding-parameters-for-imagerenditions?forum=sharepointgeneral
I think the only "solution" may be to supply a larger resolution and downscaling it with CSS.

Comment: Thanks but I mean the compression quality yeah.. the jpg artifacts are quite noticeable.

Comment: Thanks again.. yeah I figured it isn't configurable, but was still hoping for an undocumented setting somewhere. You'd think that would not be too hard to implement :-\